# How do i set a solid color desktop in Awesome3?

Tags: 11.04, awesome

I'm using version 3.4.9 (smack)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `xsetroot` program for that, with option `-solid` followed by a color code, or some nicer program like `hsetroot`, like

```
hsetroot -solid '#000000'
```

See their man pages.

Also, you should put the command in some autostart script for awesome.

Comment: xsetroot/hsetroot put me on the right path. after some puzzling figured out how to make it stick. changed the wallpaper line in my  theme.lua to: theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "hsetroot -solid '#000000'" }